# submitHandler is not working with external js

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-validate, form-submit

I have to handle changes unsaved scenario's in my jsp. I have one jsp form & two external js files.

1) When i click save button inside form, working fine.
2) If i have alert.js code as part of JSP as inline script, Working fine.
3) If i externalize alert.js and included this js as part of import, it is coming inside submit_form() function in app.js. But submitHandler is not been excuted.

**1) Jsp form**

```
I have form with inline js click event like below

    //submit form with validation
    $('button:submit').click(function() {
        submit_form('#name', '#siteId', '${add}', '${view}', 'Site');
    });


    <form:form id="form" action="${save}" commandName="site" cssClass="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator">
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled><spring:message code="form.button.site.save"/></button>
    </form:form>
```

**app.js**

```
function submit_form(name, page_id, $add_url, $view_url, page_name) {
    $form.validate({
        .
        .
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            .
            .
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
            });
        }
    });
```

**alert.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //unsaved alert section
    var unsaved = false;

    $(document).on('change', ':input', ':select', function() { //triggers change in all input/select fields including text type
        unsaved = true;
    });

    $('a.form-done').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if(unsaved === true) {
            var $modal = $('#unsaveModal');
            $modal.find(".modal-title").text("Unsaved Changes");
            $modal.find(".modal-body span").html("Changes have not been saved. Do you want to save changes?");
            $modal.find('.modal-footer .btn-warning').attr('href', $this.attr('href'));
            $modal.modal('show');
            return false;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });

    $('button:submit').click(function() {
        unsaved = false;
    });

    $('#unsaveModal .modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function() {
        $('button:submit').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#form').submit();
            $('#unsaveModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

Comment: The `.validate()` method is only used to ***initialize*** the plugin on your form and should not be placed inside a `click` or `submit` handler.

Comment: @Sparky : I want to save the form using ajax call and retain same form. And also need to show error message only on Save button click. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: [Reading the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler): Ajax belongs inside the `submitHandler`, and you can set both `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` options to `false` to force validation to only occur on submit button click.

Comment: Okay i will try this and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Please don't edit the title with "solved".  Accepting an answer below is enough.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function submit_form(name, page_id, $add_url, $view_url, page_name) {
    $form.validate({
        ....
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            ....
        }
    });
    ....
```

The `.validate()` method is only used to ***initialize*** the plugin on your form and should not be placed inside a `click` handler, and never inside a `submit` handler.  The plugin is already capturing the `click` and interrupting the `submit` event.  Putting it inside a `submit` handler will break it since the submit has already occurred before the plugin initialization was called.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $form.validate({
        ....
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // ajax here
            ....
        }
    });
    ....
```